# Fabric.js - Applying pixelate filter to resized image

Tags: fabricjs

Currently, the way Fabric.js works as far as I can tell is that its filters are applied to the original image, regardless of what it looks like on the canvas. Is there a way, by either "branching" the pixelate filter or through some other method, to have the filter be applied to the image as shown on the canvas, resized and oriented? How would I do this?

An example: I have an image within the canvas that can be resized. The user resizes it. I want to apply a filter to the *resized* version of that image, not the original uploaded image.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean applying a filter to the canvas itself? If so you could just use `toDataURL` to export the canvas to base64, create a new image, and then apply a filter to that. It might be helpful if you could provide a specific use case for what you have in mind.

Comment: Hi Melchiar -- thank you for your response. I added an example to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do. Assuming you're using the pixelate filter and want to get a consistent blocksize regardless of how big the image is on the canvas, you could simply set the filter's block size value as a function of the image's scale. By putting the `blocksize` calculation in an `object:modified` event it will recalculate each time an image is modified.

```js
canvas.on('object:modified', function(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  if(obj.type == "image") {
      var blocksize = 16 / obj.scaleX;
      obj.filters[0].blocksize = blocksize;
      obj.applyFilters();
  }
});
```